# Best material to use for soffit at camera, lighting, and outlet mounting locations

Tags: exterior, soffit

Our sub fascia was repaired as part of a reroof and all the finish fascia (cedar 1x6) was replaced.
The original soffit was made of perforated aluminum, supported at the house wall (concrete block) with F channel and secured to the sub fascia side with an L channel.  This all came down during the reroof (as expected) and was going to be reinstalled until a close inspection revealed a lot of corrosion, cracked paint (over 40 years it looks like latex paint had been applied at least once) occasional dents, dings, bends, holes, etc. We have decided to replace the material entirely.

As a note, the only support for the soffit is the sub fascia attached to the rafter tails with no structural return from sub fascia to house wall.  I.e., using wood, plywood, fiber cement products would necessitate adding any support structure shown in manufacturers installation directions.

Also, the house location is in west central Florida, less than 2 miles from the Gulf of Mexico.  I would like to use products that are resistant to termites, ants, mold, fungi, rot, and warping. And we have to meet Florida Building code for our zone.

Lastly the roof is full hip, and the overhang is 30 inches.

I am happy with using the same type of soffit material for the replacement but would like to make a change at each inside and outside corner and at some wall locations.  At these places I would like to have a 30 x 30 inch area to mount lighting, cameras, or outlets, or anything (within reason). My past experience is mounting to thin aluminum panels is not the best option.  I would of course add whatever structure is needed to support these panels and allow them to support what gets mounted to them. The panels do not need to be perforated as the code requirement for attic ventilation is easily met by the sections of soffit that would be perforated

My question is what is the best material to use for these panels?  As stated above insect resistance, mold and fungi resistance is greatly desired, the ability to hold mounting screws is also a must (hence when I thought of 1/2 inch Hardi Backer board I had to discard that idea).

Ancillary question:  when installing a board (cleat) onto the concrete block as part of the support structure do I need to use pressure treated lumber, and / or do I also need to put a moisture barrier between the block and wood (similar to the requirement we have when fastening stud walls to concrete slabs)?

Should anyone be concerned about the finish cedar fascia it was pretreated with Timbor, and when dried sufficiently multiple coats of exterior paint were applied to all sides before installation.

Comment: Not a clue what it's called, but in UK there's all different sizes (thickness and width) of shiny plastic soffit and facia board available, in up to about 5m lengths. Impervious to most of what's mentioned, and with the right backing, sturdy enough to take lights, cameras, etc. No painting needed - ever!

Comment: A picture or two of the area in question would probably be helpful, but generally, you use a soffit material that matches the siding material. If you're using vinyl/aluminum siding, use vinyl/aluminum soffit. If you've got wood siding, use wood for the soffit. If you've got brick, concrete, stucco or something else, use whatever you want for soffit. Wood would be the easiest for mounting utility boxes for outlets, etc, as it's easy to make cut outs once installed and will support some weight.